# No query result with SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Tags: mysql, sql, qt

I am trying to obtain the ID (primary key with auto increment) of the last inserted data. But my query seems to be empty after using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, while the entries are inserted correctly into the database. What is causing the problem? Thank you!

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("INSERT INTO list (file) VALUES (?); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()");
query.addBindValue(file);
qDebug() << query.exec();
qDebug() << query.first();
query.value(0).toInt();
```

Console Output:

> true
>
> false
>
> QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record

Comment: Can't I use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in my query here? I found `QSqlQuery::lastInsertId()`, is it safe to use this function (if there are other queries executed in another thread)?

Comment: @honiahaka10 . . . `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is part of SQL Server and you question is tagged MySQL.